# I have a @HTML.dropdownlistfor but has the attribute multiselect, how can i get the list of selected values?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this code is a `DropDownList` with `MultiSelect` option

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.areas,
    new MultiSelectList((SelectList)ViewBag.myareas), new { id = "idarea" })
```

but I cannot to get the list of selected values.

I trying to get this with a `List` attribute in my POCO class but returns only one value.

Comment: `but i cannot to get the list of selected values.` Are you implying that it's not getting back to your Controller? If so, post the code for the Action and Controller the `form` POST's to.

Comment: You are only getting one value because the dropdownlistfor will bind to only one field.

Comment: But How Can I get the complete List of selected values???

Comment: What is the type of areas?  What is the parameter that your action method accepts?

Answer (score 0):

Your `areas` property should be defined as:

```
public List<int> areas { get; set; }
```

Your HTML:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.areas, new MultiSelectList(Model.ListOfAreas, "AreaID", "AreaName"), new { id = "idarea" })
```

`ListOfAreas` contains all the possible `Areas` to select from.

Of course, you can create the `MultiSelectList` object in your controller, pass it along with the other data in your Model/ViewModel and in the view just use:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.areas, Model.MSLAreas, new { id = "idarea" })
```